# To print something without using cout, printf or puts()

Tags: c++, c

I had learned that

```
inline ostream & _Cdecl ostream::operator<< (const signed char * _s) {
    outstr(_s, (const signed char *)0);
    return *this;
}
```

is how the insertion operator (<<) is declared(overloaded) in the iostream.h header file. Can I possibly use the same function to print a string value on screen?

I tried

```
#include<iostream.h>
int main() {
    outstr("Hello world!", (const signed char *)0);
    return 0;
}
```

it ended up in error. I would like to use something like this in order to see if there is some possible way to answer this query of printing something on screen without using printf, cout or puts().

Update: I would welcome if you have any suggestions other than

```
#include<stdlib.h>
void main() {
    system("echo /"Hello world!/"");
}
```

NB: I have no restrictions if you can provide the C equivalent code that can print without a printf(), cout or puts()

Comment: "in the iostream.h header file" --> "in *your* iostream.h header file"

Comment: You won't be saving any significant operation time by doing this.  Also, if you want to print something without using cout, printf or puts, one solution you could try is invoking a system call.

Comment: @SidR - Could you explain that system call?

Comment: @Barmar - The function declaration is missing (Prototype for function not found).

Comment: `outstr` is presumably a private method within the implementation of the `ostream` class, so it can't be called from outside the class. Or if it's public, it needs to be called with the syntax `cout->outstr("Hellow world!", (const signed char *)0);`.

Comment: Use the system() function found in stdlib.h. Call: system("echo -n  'HelloWorld'");

Comment: @SidR when you first posted your comment I assumed you meant calling some system-specific function to the kernel's output routine (a low level call that things like printf, or the poster's outstr call might do). Calling the system() function to call echo would be a horrible horrible thing to do, and if the OP were to suggest this in an interview, he would not only fail to get the job, he would also suffer (insert ridiculous hyperbole here).

Comment: What level of portability do you require?

Comment: @mah: Could you please tell me why that would be a horrible thing to do? I would not like to make such a mistake if that was the case.

Comment: @mah: He would almost certainly suffer ridicule in an interview if he tried to do anything no port-ably clever like not using std::cout

Comment: What makes you think that the internal implementation of a C++ feature, of all things, should be tagged C?

Comment: @PascalCuoq Because printf is a C function. I had put no restrictions in using C functions in C++.

Comment: @SidR when you call `system()` you are spawning a new process, a terribly expensive operation if its purpose is only to output something. Generally (perhaps always, I am not certain), that process is a shell and the shell will then spawn a second process (for the echo command, in your case), so doubling the expense which was likely unacceptable in its single cost.

Comment: @mah: Thanks for your explanation. While I admit my understanding wasn't perfect, I was trying to answer the part of the question where he asks if it was possible to print something without using printf, cout, or puts().

Comment: @SidR - Possibly, the interviewer expected an answer and that would be right as you say. But when we look for some ways to utilize memory efficiently, its not that worthy. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want portability across all standards compliant C++ implementations, you can print a string to standard output in the following ways

```
const char * str = "Hello World\n";
fprintf(stdout, str);
fputs(str, stdout);
for (int i=0; str[i]!=0; ++i)
    putchar(str[i]);
for (int i=0; str[i]!=0; ++i)
    putc(str[i], stdout);
for (int i=0; str[i]!=0; ++i)
    fputc(str[i], stdout);
fwrite(str, sizeof(*str), strlen(str), stdout);
```

Additionally, you can use `std::cerr` and `std::clog`.  They write to `stderr` instead of `stdout`, but from the user's perspective, that's often the same place:

```
std::cerr << str;
std::clog << str;
```

From an efficiency perspective, I doubt any of these are going to help you.  For that purpose, you might want to look at something a bit more platform specific.  For POSIX systems, see the answer given by [Dave S](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13689312/440119).  For Windows, see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

What you shouldn't do, is open up your header files and imitate what they use.  At least, not at the middle levels, where they are using different various obscure functions within their own implementation.  Those functions might not exist upon the next release.  However, if you go to the deepest levels, you will find OS specific calls like the ones in the link I provided above.  Those should be safe to use as long as you stay on the same OS, or even between OS versions.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you could call the function directly, however your reasoning to do so is flawed. The time you save by eliminating the subroutine call to the operator is negligible when compared to the time taken to perform the actual function; this would be like closing the windows of your car while the convertible roof is down in order to reduce the rain.

Comment: I expect something that could answer my query rather than a remark upon it. Thanks if you could answer it.

Comment: The question you asked, very literally, is "Can I possibly use the same function to print a string value on screen?" and I answered that with the first word of my reply. Did you intend to ask why what you tried was not working? If that was your intent, it is best achieved by _actually asking_, but in this case people would not be able to answer without more information (what is happening when you try, rather than just 'not working').

Comment: Actually if the rain is not to heavy and I drive at > 60 mph but less than 75 mph (exact speed depends on rain condition) with the roof down. The inside of my convertible only gets wet when the side windows are down.  :-) Which in Seattle is useful to know with all the short sprinkles we get in summer.

Comment: You seem to have many expectations however you should first and foremost expect nothing more or less than what you actually asked for ;) Perhaps English is not your best language and there's nothing wrong with that (and I applaud your willingness to use it anyway) but you need to understand that your expectations will not be met when your communications are vague or other than what you actually are looking for. Unrelated commentary aside, @BenjaminLindley's answer includes three valid alternatives which you have not so far excluded.

Answer (score 3):

The time required to make a function call is *much*, *much* smaller than the amount of time it takes to print your string. The amount of time you might save with your approach can (and usually should) be ignored.

Comment: I want an answer to this question because it was asked to me in an interview!

Comment: Is it possible that it was a trick question? `printf`, `cout`, `puts`, etc. of course have some internal implementation, but that varies from operating system to operating system, and probably from compiler to compiler. There's no logical reason to try to re-implement standard library functions.

Comment: That was my way. If you have some other method, you may suggest.

Comment: I have to agree with @slavik262's response, and I would suggest that during an interview, the correct response is to challenge the very question (while also explaining that you know enough to go to the lower levels to perform something if it were actually required -- but it's equally important to demonstrate that you understand why it is likely not required and possibly dangerous).

Comment: The inline keyword has very little to do with code in-lining in modern compilers. Modern compiler basically ignore the term (for in-lining purposes (compiler writers found out long ago that humans are pretty bad at deciding when code should be in-lined)).

Comment: Unless I'm incorrect, `inline` forces inlines in gcc, while it is a suggestion in MSVC. Of course, at higher optimization levels, the compiler is free to inline other functions as it desires.

Comment: @slavik262: You are incorrect. Unless you start messing with flags gcc by default ignores the inline keyword (like it should (because humans are bad at this (very bad))). The compiler heuristics for determining the cost benefit from in-lining a function are pretty darn good. I it will inline as appropriate. inline is more of a linker option this morning.

Answer (score 3):

On a UNIX type system, you can do the following.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
  {
  const char x[] = "Hello World!";
  write(STDOUT_FILENO, x, strlen(x)); // Feel free to check the return value.
  return 0;
  }
```

I'm curious what your motivation for doing this would be.  Outside of signal handlers, I'm reluctant to go to the lower level calls like this.  The performance of the I/O will be the primary driver of time, not the intermediate function calls which are usually fairly heavily optimized / inlined.

Comment: I expected an answer for that question which was asked to me in an interview. Just that and thanks for the help.

Comment: I was about to write a very similar answer - you saved me the work ;) You can do the same (with other includes) on windows. btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use system calls.

http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html

This page, for example, explains linux system calls. You can start from the link I copied, and use many methods using assembly, or to say it in the other way, do something without calling the function of it.

But I'm guessing that was a trick question and if I had a company, I would never hire a person that uses system calls instead of functions.

This is an example of using sys_write(4) with standart output(1). You can inline assembly codes into your C/C++ code.
http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/#helloworld

Comment: @revani- The second link that you had provided is a purely assembly code. I expect the C code for it.

Comment: As I said, you can inline assembly into C/C++. A quick search on the internet will give you enough information to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The extraction operator is overloaded in the ostream class. So you cannot actually use it without having an object of that class with it.

It is implemented in the following manner:

```
cout<<"Hii";
```

is equivalent to:

```
cout.operator<<("Hii")
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31639950)